# Application freezes when waiting for API return code from SendGrid

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

My application is basically an email client. It's generally works fine—there are no problems or errors. When it send an email to a recipient, they successfully receive the message. When that async task completes, however, the whole application is freezing.

A hotfix that I have used is to remove the `await` keyword from the API response. This works, **but** using this approach you can't get the status code determining if the message is sent successfully since you're not waiting for the response.

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace SendMailClass{
    internal class FunctionCall{

        #region Getting user info
        static bool EmailHasBeenSend = false;
        static string Documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder
            .MyDocuments) + "\\Documents.txt";
        static string UserName = File.ReadLines(Documents).Skip(0).Take(1).First();
        static string UserEmail = File.ReadLines(Documents).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
        #endregion

        public static void SendFunction(string Recipient, string SubjectVariable,
            string CC, string BCC, String Messange,string FileName,
            string AttachmentPath)
        {
            Execute(Recipient, SubjectVariable ,CC,BCC, Messange ,FileName,
                AttachmentPath).Wait();
        }

        static async Task Execute(string Recipient, string SubjectVariable,
            string CC, string BCC, string Messange,string FileName,
            string AttachmentPath)
        {
            #region Email Values
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("InMail_Api_Key");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress(UserEmail, UserName);
            var subject = SubjectVariable == "" ? "(No subject)" : SubjectVariable;
            var to = new EmailAddress(Recipient);
            var plainTextContent = Messange == "" ? " " : Messange; ;
            var htmlContent = Messange;
            #endregion

            var Message = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject,
                plainTextContent, htmlContent);

            #region Attachment
            if (AttachmentPath != "") {
                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(AttachmentPath);
                var File = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                Message.AddAttachment(FileName, File);
            }
            #endregion

            /*
            #region CC/BCC
            if (CC != "") { 
                Message.AddCcs("anemail@example.com");
            }
            if (BCC != ""){
            Message.AddBccs("anemail@example.com")}
            #endregion
            */

            var response =await client.SendEmailAsync(Message);
            //var response =client.SendEmailAsync(Message); ---> the hotfix
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging the only results I get are from the debugger:

> The thread --- has exited with code 0 (0x0).

And at the breakpoint:

> The APIResponse is equal to **NULL**

It doesn't make any sense why it causes the application to freeze.

Comment: Try `var response = await Task.Run(() => client.SendEmailAsync(Message));` to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Btw having `static` fields that are initialized by accessing the filesystem is a really bad idea. Your app will crash horribly if the Documents.txt file is missing or locked.

Comment: Thank you Theodor for the recomendation's , the static field for the filesystem is evaluated in the main application and it wont create any problem in this subform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have mention that my last hotfix was : 
`APIResponse =client.SendEmailAsync(Message);`

I found out that this is solving the problem:

```
APIResponse = await client.SendEmailAsync(Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I want to test it a bit more before I am sure that this is the best solution.
So far the responses are **Accepted** (if email is in correct form) and **null** if the connection isn't active (no internet).